# Display Success messages on Jqgrid edit form

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

How to display a success message after successfully submitting the data to server?

Like **"Row added successfully"** on Jqgrid edit form

Comment: To get more help, you should probably edit this and say what you've tried.

Comment: I think you will have to write your own custom code for this. It would be helpful to know what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

```
afterSubmit: function () { 
    alert("Row added Successfully");    
    $(this).jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: 'xml'});     
    return [true]; },          
closeAfterAdd:true,
reloadAfterSubmit:true,
recreateForm: true,             
bottominfo:"Fields marked with (*) are required"},
```